# Matlab: plot Cubic function for range of y values

Tags: matlab, cubic

I have a cubic equation:

```
roots([9E-10 -2E-06 0.0014 0.039])
```

I am trying to plot the equation for y values of 0.0 to 0.5 (which I know gives x values in the range of 0 to 700. (i.e. the equation has been fit to this data)

```
r=0.0039-y; %where y ranges from 0.0 to 0.5
[eqnroots]=roots([9E-10 -2E-06 0.0014 r])
```

I find the real root using

```
isreal(eqnroots(n));
```

and then plot the equation but it does not give the correct x/y range and fit looks wrongs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `roots` function only yields the roots of the polynomial equation. To generate all the y-values for a given set of x-values you need to use `polyval`.

Try this:

```
% Polynomial coefficients
p = [9E-10 -2E-06 0.0014 0.039];

% Generate y-values for x-range we are interested in
x = -270:0.1:1350;
y = polyval(p,x);

% Find roots of the polynomial.
% Select any where the imaginary component is negligible, i.e. it is real.
% As it's a root, the corresponding y-value will be 0.
xroot = roots(p);
xroot = xroot(abs(imag(xroot)) < 1e-10);
yroot = zeros(size(xroot));

% Plot the polynomial and its real roots.
figure;
hold on
plot(x,y, 'b')
plot(xroot,yroot, 'rx')
```

This gives the following plot:

[image]